# Real meaning of やがて

Tags: meaning

In many pages the meaning of やがて is "in the proper time", sometimes it's "eventually"… I'd like to know all the meanings.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46866/5010

Answer (score 0):

I feel it's about observation of future but it's not completely sure to happen.
Normally, it's seen in a book not in a daily conversation.
Sometimes it's cool to use but might be taken weird.
I think the root word for that is いつか.
Casual いつか
Formal 何れ、やがて

Comment: I'm more used to seeing やがて glossed as _"presently"_. This is similarly used more often in writing than speech, and has close semantic (meaning) overlap with the Japanese term. Meanwhile, いつか is more like _"sometime"_, and いずれ is formal for どれ (_"which"_), not いつか, at least in modern Tokyo-dialect use that I'm familiar with.